# Issue with laravel IF statement when checking multiple "OR" conditions

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel application, I'm trying to check multiple conditions inside a single if statement.

I'm trying to check the following conditions,

If the logged-in user's role_id is 1 and role_name is not equal to Admin or if the logged-in user's role_id is 1 role_name is not equal to Regional Admin, the button has to be disabled

```
@if((Auth::user()->role_id=='1' && $role->name!='Admin')||(Auth::user()->role_id=='1' && $role->name!='Regional Admin'))

  <a class="btn btn-default btn_icon" href="{{ route('roles.edit',$role->id,false) }}"><img class="nc-icon" alt="edit" src="{{ asset('admin_icons/edit.svg') }}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Éditer" ></a>
```

But this condition keep fails. The button does not get disabled even if the both conditions are true...

Comment: `@if(Auth::user()->role_id == '1' && ($role->name!=='Admin'||$role->name!=='Regional Admin'))` try like this. I will be work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the below `if` statement as per your requirement.

```
@if( (Auth::user()->role_id=='1') && ( $role->name != 'Admin' && $role->name!='Regional Admin' ) )

    // Button disable

@else
    // Show button

@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like that --

```php
   @if(Auth::user()->role_id=='1' && !in_array($role->name,['Admin', 'Regional Admin'])
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your description you need to use `AND` condition instead of `OR` Condition

```
@if((Auth::user()->role_id=='1' && $role->name!='Admin')&& (Auth::user()->role_id=='1' && $role->name!='Regional Admin'))

  <a class="btn btn-default btn_icon" href="{{ route('roles.edit',$role->id,false) }}"><img class="nc-icon" alt="edit" src="{{ asset('admin_icons/edit.svg') }}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Éditer" ></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@if((Auth::user()->role_id=='1') && ($role->name!='Admin' || ($role->name!='Regional Admin'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

=> **role_id** is field with type **integer**

=> **$role->name** is field with type **varchar**

and then replace your condition with below:

```
@if((Auth::user()->role_id == 1 && !($role->name === 'Admin'))||(Auth::user()->role_id == 1 && !($role->name === 'Regional Admin')))
```

Answer (score 0):

used **And** method in laravel blade like this,

```
@if( (Auth::user()->role_id=='1') && ( $role->name != 'Admin' || $role->name!='Regional Admin' ) )
 // show disable button
@else
@endif
```

Or also used the **in_array** method

```
@if(Auth::user()->role_id=='1' && !in_array($role->name,['Admin', 'Regional Admin'])
```